# Detect whether headset has microphone

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I need to detect whether the plugged in wired headset has microphone or not.

I can check if a headset is plugged in using [isWiredHeadSetOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn()), but for microphone does not seem to be such a method in AudioManager class.

I have found some suggestions using [ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG), but I am interested to find out this information even if the headset has been plugged in before opening my application, this event won't be fired during the lifetime of my app.

Any ideas regarding this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you need it ? that's up to the user to know where the microphone is

Comment: Because I want to connect a flash through audio jack and this helps me differentiate between 2 types of flash.

Comment: a flash in the audio socket ? we can do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Go ahead and register `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` in your activity's `onResume()`.
If user has ever plugged in/out her headset after boot-up, platform will deliver the latest state to your activity when it resumes.

Following test code worked:

```
package com.example.headsetplugtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class HeadSetPlugIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(action)) {
                Log.d("HeadSetPlugInTest", "state: " + intent.getIntExtra("state", -1));
                Log.d("HeadSetPlugInTest", "microphone: " + intent.getIntExtra("microphone", -1));
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that onReceive() is called also when the activity is started

Comment: Aren't device connection broadcasts of the `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY` kind? I.e. "when sending a broadcast only registered receivers will be called -- no BroadcastReceiver components will be launched" - or as described clearer by Dianne Hackborn: "It's only given to those who call registerReceiver, and not sent to receivers declared in manifests."