# List of connected audio input devices on Android

Tags: java, android

My application must record sound only from external microphone. Is there a way to get list of available microphones?

I'm using `AudioRecord` for sound capturing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious. What phone model supports more than 1 microphone? I'm aware of a few where you could plug in an integrated mic+speaker headset, but in such cases, they disable the existing microphone.

Comment: Having a wired headset connected doesn't really disable the internal mic; it just gives the external mic higher priority than the internal mic(s) for _most_ audiosources (not necessarily true e.g. for the `CAMCORDER` audiosource). I'm guessing that the OP wants to detect whether an external mic is connected and only record audio if that's the case.

Comment: Exactly, I have a custom microphone and app shouldn't record signal unless it is connected.

Answer (score 3):

The applicable solution for me I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709309/1050541). And added the following code:

```
private static boolean headsetMic;

private static BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(action)) {
            final int headphones = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            final int mic = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", -1);
            // we need to check both of them, because if headset with
            // mic was disconnected mic is 1 but headphones is 0, and
            // actually no external mic is connected
            headsetMic = headphones > 0 && mic > 0;
        }
    }
};

public static boolean isExternalMicConnected() {
    return headsetMic;
}
```

I call `isExternalMicConnected()` and it shows if custom mic was connected.