# how to detect plugging in and pulling out microphone in android

Tags: android

How do I detect whether there is a microphone plugged into my device?
Also, how do I get notification if the microphone is pulled out from the device?

I can't seem to see it in the android docs on how to do this, neither in my google searches.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you'd need to detect the headset first, then check if it has a microphone. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708636/detect-whether-headset-has-microphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`, if min sdk is 21, is recommended to use the other constant `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`.

You will receive a "sticky" `Intent` when you register the receiver, and then others when the mic is plugged in/out. The `BroadcastReceiver` is pretty simple, couldn't find a documentation for "state" and "microphone" keys, just saw them with the debugger. So the class could look like:

```
class MicrophonePluggedInReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) {
            val state = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0)
            val microphone = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0)
            val isMicrophonePluggedIn = state == 1 && microphone == 1
            Toast.makeText(context, "microphone plugged in $isMicrophonePluggedIn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And then you just need to register (and unregister)

```
val microphonePluggedReceiver = MicrophonePluggedInReceiver()

// ...

context.registerReceiver(microphonePluggedReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG))    

// ...

unregisterReceiver(microphonePluggedReceiver)
```